# Is it possible to prove an argument is not satiable with equivalences?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove is this argument: (p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∧(p ∨ ¬q) ∧(¬p ∨ ¬q) is satiable with equivalence. Is what I said below valid for this?

(p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∧(p ∨ ¬q) ∧(¬p ∨ ¬q)

q ∨ (p ∧ ¬p) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q) Distribution

q ∨ F ∧(p ∨ ¬q) ∧(¬p ∨ ¬q) Contradiction

q ∧ (p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q) Identity

q ∧ (¬q ∨ (p ∧ ¬p) Distribution

q ∧ (¬q ∨ F) Contradiction

q ∧ ¬q Identity

F Contradiction

Cannot be satisfied since this statement is an absurdity and always false no matter the combinations of truth values.

Comment: Sorry, that was very rude of me. The question was a duplicate and I didn't want the mods getting mad.... Anyway I can make it up to you? :/

Comment: I'll let it go, Brandon.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me out a ton and I should have given you rep and not thought of myself :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the distributive law at the start, *twice* to greatly simplify your proof that the proposition is a contradiction (i.e., not true under *any* truth-value assignment).

$$\begin{align} (p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∧(p ∨ ¬q) ∧(¬p ∨ ¬q) &\equiv (q \lor (p\land \lnot p)) \land ((p \land \lnot p)\lor \lnot q) \\ \\ 
&\equiv (q \lor F) \land (F \lor \lnot q)\\ \\
&\equiv (q \land \lnot q) \\ \\ 
&\equiv F\end{align}$$

Comment: You're the God of discrete, are you a computer scientist?

Comment: I'm a mathematician who loves logic, and thoroughly enjoys computer science and all things discrete (and much much more)! ;-)